# Selenium ChromeDriver - HTTP 407 on driver.quit()

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am behind a proxy server. Using Selenium 2.39, Python 2.7.6 and ChromeDriver 2.9, whenever I call `.quit()` on an instance of Chrome, I get an HTTP 407 error. No such error occurs when using FirefoxDriver.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Tetrinity\Desktop\chrometest.py", line 7, in <module>
    browser.quit()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.39.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 82, in quit
    self.service.stop()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.39.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\chrome\service.py", line 97, in stop
    url_request.urlopen("http://127.0.0.1:%d/shutdown" % self.port)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 407: Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy service is denied.  )
```

The problem can be reduced to the following script, which I have saved as `chrometest.py` (as seen in the above stacktrace):

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("http://www.google.co.uk")
browser.quit()
```

This script successfully opens Chrome and navigates to Google. The `.quit()` then causes the above crash, leaving a dead ChromeDriver instance lying around. What could be causing this, and how can I prevent it?

Research has turned up a lot of answers that [aren't quite relevant](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/selenium-users/127c3bxsjf/calling-driver-quit-crashes-chromedriver-exe), [overcomplicate things](http://www.testingthewaterhouse.com/2013/07/dealing-with-driverquit-crashes-where.html) or [claim it's an issue that was already fixed](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=99).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I wasted several hours today trying to track down a solution, I thought I'd document what worked for me. I fixed this problem by opening Internet Options > Connections > LAN settings > Advanced and inserting `127.0.0.1` into the Exceptions box. After doing this, `chrometest.py` completed without error and the ChromeDriver window was successfully closed.

Credit for this solution should go to the question-asker [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182482/how-to-use-chomedriver-with-a-proxy-for-selenium-webdriver). Oddly enough, this question never appeared in my searches. It appeared in the Similar Questions section when I was nearly finished typing up the original version of this question (go figure!).

Comment: I have given the same output in Pictorial format. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue on Chrome browser. The following steps will give you the fix.

1| Uncheck the Check Box, `By Proxy server for local address`

[image]

2| Click on Advanced Tab

[image]

3| Enter `127.0.0.1` under Exceptions panel

4| Click ok